# Finding a cycle in an undirected graph vs finding one in a directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

So I'm reading Robert Sedgewick's Algorithms 4th ed. book and the methods for finding a cycle in a directed graph is different than the one for finding a cycle in an undirected graph.

Here is example code to find a Cycle in an undirected graph

```
public class Cycle {
   public boolean[] marked;
   public boolean hasCycle;

   public Cycle(Graph G) {
      marked = new boolean[G.V()]; // G.V() is the number of vertices in the graph G
      for (int s = 0; s < G.V(); ++s) {
         if (!marked[s])
            dfs(G, s, s);
      }
   }

   private void dfs(Graph G, int v, int u) {
      marked[v] = true;
      for (int w : G.adj(v)) //iterate through vertices adjacent to v
         if (!marked[w])
            dfs(G, w, v)
         else if (w != u) hasCycle= true;
   }

   public boolean hasCycle() {
      return hasCycle;
   }
}
```

However, when trying to find a cycle in a directed graph, Sedgewick uses a boolean array where the ith element of that array is true if the ith vertex has been examined during the current call stack. For every vertex K examined, we check to see if the Kth element of the boolean array is true. If it is, then we have a cycle. My question is, why is it necessary to use that boolean array for a directed graph. Shouldn't the approach I just listed be more memory-efficient? And does this approach only work for undirected graphs? why?

Comment: maybe he assume there could be a self loop in directed graph?

Comment: It's without assuming a self-loop actually. I think that the algorithm I just posted might work for directed graphs, I'm just unsure

Comment: the answer below makes sense..

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can't use the same algorithm: The algorithm above simply explores all connected components of the graph. If you encounter an already marked vertex, there must be **two different paths** to reach it, and in an **undirected graph there must be a cycle**. If not, you can continue with the next connected component - no need to clean up the component you just finished.

On the other hand, if you have a **directed graph**, two different paths to the same vertex **don't make a cycle**. So you need a different algorithm (for example, you may need to clean up any steps you back track.)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Just came up with a counterexample 

http://i.imgur.com/uBWTZ.png